# GeoServer problem zoom levels

Tags: geoserver, rendering, geopackage

I have created the layer (geopackage data file) and when I do layer preview from, don't appeared tiles in the different zoom levels. Also I have tested in QGIS and everything is ok. Attached case you can find image in different zoom scales[image]

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: one of your layers is being used at the wrong scale

Comment: Hi Ian,  Is only one layer. the images are in the different scale zoom for the same layer.

Comment: Please, may anyone to support me? Regards